# Visual Studio 2015 editor removes line continuation character in Visual Basic source code

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio 2015 Pro gives the following **error**:

> error BC36716: Visual Basic 9.0 does not support implicit line
>   continuation.

For the following source **code**:

```
1     .Line.Points = New UnitPoint() _

2              {

3                New UnitPoint(Offset + OutlineBoxWidth_halph, 0),

4                New UnitPoint(Offset + OutlineBoxWidth_halph, "height"),

5                New UnitPoint(Offset + OutlineBoxWidth, "height")


6               }
```

When I insert continuation character on lines 2 to 5, the editor removes it when I move the cursor off that line

It used to compile fine but something has changed. What?

Comment: Yet another casualty of the Roslyn integration.  VB version 9.0 was 4 versions ago, VS2015 supports VB version 14.  Targeting an old version of VB.NET is technically possible although not easy.  My crystal ball says that your .vbproj file contains `<LangVersion>`.  You'll want to remove that with a text editor to get ahead.  Click the New Issue button in [this web page](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues) to report this issue.  Although it isn't very likely they'll fix this.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well spotted. it was <LangVersion> in .vbproj

Answer (score 3):

It was `<LangVersion>` in .vbproj.

Comment: VB.NET v9 maps to framework 3.5 so until your project can be updated to v4.0 or higher ([VB 10 maps to framework 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637436.aspx)) you have to revert the line endings.

Comment: I do not have that line in my vbproj file. Did MS change the structure?

Comment: Every time I experienced the fault l found that vbproj file contained <LangVersion> that I had to remove.